# Optimal strategy in a game of football

Tags: probability, optimization, stochastic-processes

You're the manager of a football  team that plays against a weaker opponent. You can choose between playing defensively and offensively. When playing defensively, goals occur as Poisson events with rate $\mu_1$. When playing offensively, goals occur Poisson with rate $\mu_2$, $\mu_2 >\mu_1$. If a goal occurs, it's scored by your team with probability $p > 0.5$, and thus conceded by your team  with probability $1-p$, for both tactics.  You can switch between the two tactics as many times as you wish. What is the optimal strategy, giving the highest chance to win the game?

I get that we start by playing  offensively, and switch to defensively if the lead is large and the remaining time is little. But is it possible to calculate the boundary exactly?

Comment: Try setting it up as a dynamic programming problem over a finite horizon, with (your_score, opponent_score) as the state. Even the goal differential might suffice as the state.

Comment: Like how you would maximize ticket revenue, I recall that! Make time discrete and then work back to t=0